# TypeError: transferMoney() missing 1 required positional argument: 'amount'

Tags: python

Hi ive looked at other threads like this but cant find a fix... 
Im only including the code where the problem occurs, there is more code but the rest is irreverent.

```
 def transferMoney(self, sender_account, receiver_name, receiver_account_no, amount):
    self.sender_account = found_customer
    self.reciver_name = customer_name = input("\nPlease input customer name \n")
    customer = self.search_customers_by_name(customer_name)




 def run_admin_options(self, admin):

    loop = 1
    while loop == 1:
        choice = self.admin_menu(admin.get_name())
        if choice == 1:
            customer_name= input("Please Enter The Name Of The Customer Sending Money: ")
            sender_account_no= int(input("Please Enter the Account Number Of The Person Sending Money: "))
            recipient_name= input("Please Enter the name of the person reciving money: ")
            recipient_account_no= int(input("Please Enter the recipient account number: "))

            found_recipient= self.search_customers_by_name(recipient_name)
            found_customer= self.search_customers_by_name(customer_name)
            if found_recipient ==None:
                return ("Customer Not Found")
            else:
                if found_customer != None:
                    my_account= found_customer.get_account()
                    receiver_account= found_recipient.get_account()
                    amount_transfer= float(input("Please Enter Amount You Would Like To Send: "))
                    transferMoney= self.transferMoney(my_account, receiver_account, amount_transfer)
```

Comment: Its exactly as the error message is saying, you forgot a parameter when you called the function.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the `receiver_name` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please give receiver_name parameter value to your function.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of code you provided you do not have receiver_account_no being passed in. As of now your program thinks the receiver_account_no is actually the amount to be transferred. This leaves the expected amount argument not being passed in.